# tensorflow object detection...python model_main_tf2.py --model_di .... command cause error utf-8

Tags: python, tensorflow

I command as below

```
(tensorflow1) C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection>python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8 --pipeline_config_path=ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/pipline.config --num_train_steps=10000
```

and it causes error

```
The versions of TensorFlow you are currently using is 2.6.0-rc1 and is not supported.
Some things might work, some things might not.
If you were to encounter a bug, do not file an issue.
If you want to make sure you're using a tested and supported configuration, either change the TensorFlow version or the TensorFlow Addons's version.
You can find the compatibility matrix in TensorFlow Addon's readme:
https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  UserWarning,
2021-07-19 02:06:57.472871: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2021-07-19 02:06:57.473198: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1835] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-07-19 02:06:57.480144: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
WARNING:tensorflow:There are non-GPU devices in `tf.distribute.Strategy`, not using nccl allreduce.
W0719 02:06:57.487872 21340 cross_device_ops.py:1387] There are non-GPU devices in `tf.distribute.Strategy`, not using nccl allreduce.
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',)
I0719 02:06:57.503646 21340 mirrored_strategy.py:369] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 115, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\pedro\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\pedro\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\pedro\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 112, in main
    record_summaries=FLAGS.record_summaries)
  File "C:\Users\pedro\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 499, in train_loop
    pipeline_config_path, config_override=config_override)
  File "C:\Users\pedro\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\config_util.py", line 138, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
    proto_str = f.read()
  File "C:\Users\pedro\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 117, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "C:\Users\pedro\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 80, in _preread_check
    compat.path_to_str(self.__name), 1024 * 512)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 106: invalid start byte
```

I really don't know why it cause utf-8 error. my window's host name is all english and all csv files only consist of english.

I follows two reference to implement.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rgpfk6eYxJA&t=1139s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDXdlXlaCco&t=1584s

Comment: 'The versions of TensorFlow you are currently using is 2.6.0-rc1 and is not supported.'

Have you tried another version of Tensorflow, like 2.5?

Comment: Same. after installing tensorflow version 2.5.0